# Is a constructor considered an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is a constructor considered an object in JavaScript?

A constructor usually has `.this` in the body.

Also, it seems like a constructor is used to create an object. Constructors look very similar to functions and functions are objects. Is that correct?

Comment: Consider `Date`. It’s a constructor (`new Date();`) but also has properties (`Date.UTC();`), thus behaving like an object. A constructor still has the type `"function"`. I’m not sure whether this _function vs. object_ terminology is really all that useful.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are functions, functions in javascript is also an Objects

```
function foo() {}
foo.someProp = 'some prop'
console.log(foo.someProp); // prints 'some prop'
console.log(foo.name); // prints 'foo'
```

Comment: It says a constructor is a special kind of function...;

Comment: constructor is a function that returns an Object